# keep the original symbol when adding text into XML tag using dom4j

Tags: xml, dom4j

I am using the dom4j to create XML string in Java. There is a sentence such as "the age > 10 and number < 11."
I do the following code

```
String wholeText = "the age > 10 and number < 11.";
Element text = section.addElement("text");  
text.addText(wholeText);
```

when I show the text content, it was converted as

```
"the age &gt; 10 and number &lt; 11."
```

the "<" and ">" symbol was converted to the html string.
Does any way to keep the original symbol when I add text into XML tag using dom4j?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some characters (especially `<`) have to be escaped this way unless you wrap the content in a CDATA section.

To make it a CDATA section from dom4j, you could use

```
String wholeText = "the age > 10 and number < 11.";
Element text = section.addElement("text");  
text.addCDATA(wholeText);
```